# Question related Duplicate content. (Robot meta)

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, meta-tags, woocommerce

So I created this amazon affiliate ecommerce sites. Basically all the products data are copied from the amazon.

My homepage is original content, but all my products pages are duplicate content, by that, I mean an exact copy from the amazon's sites.

My ideal solution would be to get all my pages indexed in google even if they don't rank high. But I do want to rank for my homepage, which is original content.

So is it possible for my product pages to get indexed in the google but still not let them effect the ranking of my home page, by adding this `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">` meta tags on my product pages.

or the duplicate content will still effect the ranking of my home page even if I set the robot meta tags of duplicate pages to nofollow, because they belong to the same domain as the homepage.

or is it better to just go with `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">.` that way they don't effect the my homepage at all.

Just learned about all this robot meta tags today, so little confuse.

Comment: This is duplicate content and bad for your website. Hide them completely from Google.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the duplicate content issues you can use the following options-

1. `< META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` -
   This tells the Google Spider not to crawl that page (http://www.metatags.org/meta_name_robots).
2. `Disallow: [the URL path you want to block]` -
   Products directories can be blocked.Here there is no need to include the code to every single page (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en).

The following methods suggests Google Robots not to crawl your website.Since your website is not crawled, then there will be no issues regarding the Duplicate content.

So I recommend the second method in this case because it is easier.

Comment: "Spider not to crawl that page" -- technically this is not correct. A "noindex, nofollow" tag will not prevent the spider from crawling the page. The spider has to crawl the page in order to see the meta tag! But if this tag is in place, Google will not *index* the page, and will treat all links on the page as nofollow. Your second suggested method will prevent crawling though.

Comment: Please elaborate this first message with any links/notes.  Does the second method help in duplicate content then?

Comment: The second method will prevent crawling, so can be very useful in cases of duplicate content. The first method does not prevent crawling, but does prevent indexing. You can read Google's own docs on this [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0):

this is duplicated content, and it is unlikely that they will be indexed in any case even if you use set meta=noindex. Especially so when the content comes directly from amazon affiliate (did u place a script or do an iframe for your product pages? If it's an embed script, they might already be a nofollow meta from amazon.

On that note however, a follow could help with your rankings as it just tells google bots more about your content relevance (group).